# Ways to upload code and other metadata to Production

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, metadata, change-set

What are the best options to deploy metadata from Sandbox to Production?
Our installation consists of many installed managed packages, custom objects, fields and a lot of Apex code.

1. We had used change sets in the past but seem to be too slow.
2. Is it possible through VS Code to retrieve source from a manifest and then deploy it directly to another environment? I have observed that only code is included in my manifest.
3. Would it be better through GitLab? Salesforce had a GitLab trailhead cause i am interested in trying to integrate our SF with gitLab, but i miss of documentation/necessary steps. If anyone has done the integration i would appreciate a high level description of the steps needed.

Comment: Personally I would move away from "happy soup" to unlocked packages and simply install those. Of course, this requires admins to change their behaviour so as to refrain from modifying even unlocked package metadata OR inform your implementers if they make changes to metadata from those packages (or it becomes a requirement to pull metadata back to git before further dev effort is applied). This has several benefits not least of which is more rigour around changes, which will include testing that is against a setup that is fully aligned with production.

Comment: paid devops tools are another option - Copado, Gearset, etc.